# Limit Results with WP Visual Bakery Visual Composer

Tags: wordpress

This has to do with Wordpress Visual Composer, WP-Bakery, etc.

I have a snippet in a WP page that renders all events into a tiled display. I'd like to limit this output to 3 results but I'm not sure what shortcode to use for this as I can't find a limit or anything like that in the shortcode docs on WP VisualComposer's site. I've tried limit="3", Total_items="3", and everything else that I'm used to seeing.

> [events grid="3" views="all" start_date=""]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Composer uses the WP_Query

```
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/
```

which you can covert to a shortcode via http_build_query and figure out what to use.

adding this to your query:

```
&posts_per_page=3
```

is the same as this in PHP:

```
'posts_per_page' => 3
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.